# Detect Keyboard IME language on Android

Tags: android

How can I detect which language is use typing into EditText. I know the API 13 has [`getCurrentInputMethodSubtype`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#getCurrentInputMethodSubtype%28%29), but what is the alternate for older versions?

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem right now..

Answer (score 2):

There is none.  And I wouldn't count on even that above working across all keyboards.  I wrote a popular keyboard and have no idea where the framework would get that info from-  there's no API for them to query what keyboard type we are or for us to update if we switched (say from a user using an in keyboard switch language shortcut).

The keyboard API is really Google's bastard stepchild.  They don't seem to put a lot of thought into it, or work with other major keyboard makers when adding new functionality.