# android detect current charset on keyboard

Tags: android, character-encoding, keyboard

In android, is there a way to programatically detect the current charset (or language) that is being used on the keyboard?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm aware this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156642/detect-keyboard-ime-language-on-android but that question was never answered